# Restarting Managed Server in weblogic using weblogic API

Tags: java, weblogic

My company wants to automate the process of managing server, one of the requirement is to automate restarting the managed servers. Is there any way I can do that using java code. may be with weblogic APIs ? In brief I need to restart managed server whenever a request comes for restarting the managed server by email.

Ravi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible using [JMX](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13728/accesswls.htm) and specifically the `ServerRuntimeMBean` within Weblogic has methods to stop and restart.

A full [example is given here](http://verticalhorizons.in/jmx-client-code-to-start-stop-suspend-and-resume-weblogic-server-using-serverruntimembean/)